How to read struct field in Hudi
We are using Scala Spark and written a dataframe having struct column in hudi. But while reading the same using Hudi, it is giving error -
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow cannot be cast to class org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnarBatch

Schema of dataframe :
root
 | - id : String
 | - address : Struct
       | - Street : String 
       | - City : String

(ignoring _hoodie columns)
